# how to build a new tagset

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk

I have a corpus of a language that has not been POS annotated before, that is, it has no existing tagset.
Apart from manually tagging it with a word processor like notepad, is there any automatic approach to start tagging a new untagged set like my corpus?.
Thanks.

Comment: What language is the corpus in?

Comment: Also, you are using the term "tag set" in a slightly non-standard way. A tag set is all the parts of speech a **language** has.  For example, English is often analysed using the Penn tag set, meaning that each word in a corpus is assigned one of the tags in the Penn tag set. Because linguists often disagree on what parts of speech a language has, you can have multiple tag sets per language.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. . .tag set.

Comment: I am correct in thinking you want an automatic way of assigning a part of speech to each token in a corpus, and **not** a way of creating a tag set?

Comment: yes! considering the fact that this corpus in question has not been POS tagged before. It just like from scratch process. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how detailed the tagset should be. 10-12 basic POS (Noun, Adjective, ..., foreign, punctuation) or more detailed (distinguishing verb forms, types of pronouns, gender, number, tense, ...).

The former is pretty much universal (see  [the categories of the Multext-East tagset](http://nl.ijs.si/ME/Vault/V3/msd/html/msd.html#SECTION04100000000000000000) or Google's universal tagset).

The latter is much more complicated, we have a [paper](http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/~hana/bib/hana-feldman-2010-morph-law.pdf) about it. In short, we have a template for tagsets, then we modify it (dropping/adding categories and values) to suit a particular language.

Regarding annotation: again, it depends - if you have a small tagset you can just manually assign a tag to each word, say in Notepad or some simple GUI (we use [this one](http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/~hana/law.html), but there are probably better ones). If you have a tagset with hundreds or thousand tags, then you probably want some better support for it. The best thing is to use a (possibly overgenerating) morphological analyzer and a GUI allowing to choose from the options the analyzer suggests.

Comment: thanks Jirka. can I please contact you for more discussion since it looks like there are experiences you have that will help me. The resources you recommended really opened my mind.

Comment: Yes, use the email on my webpage (purl.org/jh) and remind me if I don't reply within a week or so, I probably wont till Monday.

Answer (score 0):

[Brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/) has a very nice GUI for manual annotation.